# Lightadmin and RepositoryNotFoundException while saving an entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, lightadmin

JPA entity class:

```
@Entity(name="job_configuration")
public class JobConfiguration extends AbstractEntity {
    String name;

    @Lob
    String value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="job_id")
    Job job;
}
```

Lightadmin administration class:

```
public class JobConfigurationAdministration 
    extends AdministrationConfiguration<JobConfiguration> {
}
```

and now while trying to update/add a JobConfiguration entry Lightadmin throws a Spring exception `org.springframework.data.rest.repository.RepositoryNotFoundException`:

```
RepositoryNotFoundException: No repository found for name job_configuration
```

list and view works fine. Any clues?

---

Update: I know what is causing this behavior the following declaration inside `Job`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="job", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
Set<JobConfiguration> jobConfigurations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the cause of this issue:

```
@Entity(name="job_configuration")
```

if this entity is persisted in the default table name i.d. `JobConfiguration` then this issue is gone. It looks as a bug in Lightadmin/Spring.

The workaround is to change the above to:

```
@Entity
```